# Uncaught Error on using Axios PUT in React "Uncaught (in promise) Error status 400"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm having an error while updating a record in my API using Axios.Put, and i can't seem to find solution on this problem and also i'm not able to understand it fully on what does it want to tell me.

This is my update component where i use PUT to update a record.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Update() {
const [ProductDescription, setProductDescription] = useState('');
const [ProductCount, setProductCount] = useState('');

const [id, setID] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
    setID(localStorage.getItem('productID'))
    setProductDescription(localStorage.getItem('productDescription'));
    setProductCount(localStorage.getItem('productCount'));
}, []);


const updateAPIData = () => {
    axios.put(`https://localhost:44380/api/products/`+id, {
       ProductDescription,
       ProductCount
    }).then(response => {
        if(response.data !=null) {
            alert("Update Successfully")
        }
    })
}

    return (
        <div>
            <Form className="create-form">
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Product Description </label>
                    <input placeholder='Product Description' value={ProductDescription} onChange={(e) => setProductDescription(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Product Count</label>
                    <input placeholder='Product Count' value={ProductCount} onChange={(e) => setProductCount(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Button type='submit' onClick={updateAPIData}>Update</Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
};
```

I have also used this code but still having the same error

```
axios.put(`https://localhost:44380/api/products/${id}'
```

And this is how i get the data on my other component using a button

```
    const [ProductDescription, setProductDescription] = useState('');
    const [ProductCount, setProductCount] = useState('');

    const [id, setID] = useState(null);

        useEffect(() => {
        setID(localStorage.getItem('productID'))
        setProductDescription(localStorage.getItem('productDescription'));
        setProductCount(localStorage.getItem('productCount'));
}, []);


    const setData = (data) => {
        let { productID, productDescription, productCount } = data;
        localStorage.setItem('productID', productID);
        localStorage.setItem('productDescription', productDescription);
        localStorage.setItem('productCount', productCount);

<IconButton><Edit onClick={() => setData(data)}/></IconButton>
```

I do get `undefined` data using the localStorage, why could that be?

Comment: you know what a 400 error means?

Comment: Can you pleas check the result of local-storage value for productID?

Comment: [400 error](https://httpstatuses.com/400)

Comment: Your server is returning an error code 400. So you are probably sending some wrong data or some data the server can't understand. But without knowing what the server expects, nobody can help you. But the `{details}` body seems rather strange. Especially, because the `details` object seems to contain a function `setProductCount`

Comment: e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing - now, I'm no expert, but I doubt it's the last two, my guess is your request doesn't meet the server requirements for the request

Comment: when i use the console when fetching the data and send it to `setData` i get an `undefined`. could that be the problem?